# Android NDK sem_wait reporting 100% cpu use

Tags: android, android-ndk, semaphore, cpu-usage

The android Profiler shows one of my native threads as using 100% cpu, yet this thread is only calling `sem_wait` on a semaphore that is not signalled:

```
int rc;
do {
    rc = sem_wait(&m_sema);
} while (rc == -1 && errno == EINTR);
```

I have added a breakpoint on the while condition and added logging after `sem_wait` and can confirm that the call to `sem_wait` never returns.

Is this spurious CPU usage against a debug build, or is this call actually using CPU cycles on devices?

This semaphore is part of [MoodyCamel' C++11 SPSC Blocking Queue](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue/blob/master/blockingconcurrentqueue.h#L196) which does not seem to have any issues otherwise.